# URL path of ionic application

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have craeted a blank ionic project and starting to build on it. I successfully created the blank project and it works as expected.

The app is available at

```
http://localhost/Projects/myapp/www/index.html
```

Now I want to add some routes to the project and so I have added the below code in the app.js file.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('blogs', {
        url : "/blogs",
        templateUrl : "templates/blogs.html",
        controller : "BlogsCtrl"
    });
})
```

As the URL route is /blogs, I tried to access it across all types of combinations. But I get page not found error.

What's the actual url, where I can access /blogs page? Below are the few combinations that I tried.

```
http://localhost/Projects/myapp/www/index.html/blogs
http://localhost/Projects/myapp/www/index.html/#blogs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If URL defined as `/blogs`

The full path should be:

```
<AppRoot>/#/blogs
```

In your case:

```
http://localhost/Projects/myapp/www/#/blogs
```

You don't need to use `index.html` anyways:

```
http://localhost/Projects/myapp/www/#/index.html/blogs
```

Generally if you use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise`:

for example

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/blogs");
```

After, you can just write  `http://localhost/Projects/myapp/www/#/`

---

**--  MAC  --**

If you test GUI on MAC, you can run:

```
cd to-your-project www
```

run:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

And after the URL will look like:

```
http://localhost:8000/#/blogs
```

Comment: This does not give page not found error.. But it still shows the home page. Even if I try someother URI also, it does not give any error, which actually it should. I am trying /random-text but it still shows the homep age.

Comment: @Purus do you use `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/blogs");` ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is:

```
$ cd Projects/myapp
$ ionic serve

Running dev server: http://192.168.1.4:8100
Running live reload server: http://192.168.1.4:35729
```

And you have live reload too! Enjoy